# Haskell adding element to an existing list

Tags: database, list, haskell

The function I want to write is to enable the user to type their name in and the film they would like to become a fan of.

This is the current code i'm using:

```
type Title = String
type Actor = String
type Cast = [Actor]
type Year = Int
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]
type Period = (Year, Year)
type Film = (Title, Cast, Year, Fans)
type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: Database
testDatabase = [("Casino Royale", ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"], 2006, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
    ("Cowboys & Aliens", ["Harrison Ford", "Daniel Craig", "Olivia Wilde"], 2011, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]),     
        ("Catch Me If You Can", ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Tom Hanks"], 2002, ["Zoe", "Heidi", "Jo", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Kevin", "Tim"]),           
            ("Mamma Mia!", ["Meryl Streep", "Pierce Brosnan"], 2008, ["Kevin", "Jo", "Liz", "Amy", "Sam", "Zoe"])]
```

Using this as the type:

```
becomeFan :: String -> String -> [Film] -> [Film]
```

Am I able to perform this task for example, If user "Bob" wants to become a fan of film "Mamma Mia!" then the database would update the fans list from:

```
["Kevin", "Jo", "Liz", "Amy", "Sam", "Zoe"]
```

to:

```
["Bob", "Kevin", "Jo", "Liz", "Amy", "Sam", "Zoe"]
```

Thanks in advance to all the provided answers!!

Comment: Did you try to write this function? What did it look like? What happened?

Comment: Should that be `becomeFan :: Title -> Fan -> Database -> Database` or `becomeFan :: Fan -> Title -> Database -> Database`? After defining all those type synonyms it's a shame not to use them...

Comment: Your right, that would be a better type to use for the function and make it clearer

Answer (score 6):

This is a neat example since creating an `Endo`, i.e. a function `a -> a` like your `[Film] -> [Film]` is a great way to handle "state" in a stateless language. Let's dive in.

---

So the goal is to create a function like `becomeFan "Joseph" "7 1/2" :: [Film] -> [Film]` is a "film database update function". To perform this update, you need to modify the film database to update the list of fans for the film `"7 1/2"` to include `"Joseph"`. We'll assume that each user's name is globally unique and write this function several times.

Let's assume, for now, that if the film isn't in our database, then `becomeFan` doesn't do anything and that the database contains no duplicates.

First we have the direct recursive version.

```
becomeFan _ _ [] = [] -- empty film database
becomeFan name film (f@(title, cast, year, fans) : fs)
  | film == title = (title, cast, year, name:fans) : fs
  | otherwise     = f : becomeFan name film fs
```

Which will just iterate down the list of films in the database and make our update iff the flim title matches the one we're trying to edit. Note the `@`-syntax which allows us to have the film we're examining "as a whole" and still deconstruct it.

The challenges with this method are myriad, though—it's just very complex! We have a number of basic assumptions tied into the way we implement `becomeFan` which may become desynched with other functions we write. Fortunately, Haskell is *very* good at fixing problems like that.

The first step is to introduce some more powerful data types.

---

What we'll do is eliminate some of the type synonyms and introduce some more powerful container types, in particular `Set` which behaves like a mathematical set and `Map` which is like a dictionary or hash.

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.Map as Map
```

We also use a "record" type for `Film`. Records are isomorphic to ("functionally equivalent to") tuples, but have named fields which are useful for documentation and let us use fewer type synonyms.

```
type Name = String
type Year = Int
data Film = Film { title :: Title, cast :: Set Name, year :: Year, fans :: Set Name)
```

By using a `Map Title Film` to represent our database, we also get to guarantee uniqueness of films (a `Map` makes keys of `Title` to either zero or one `Film`s—we can't have multiple matches). The downside here is that we might desync the `Title` in the `Database` keys with the `Title` in the `Film` type itself.

```
type Database = Map Title Film
```

So how can we rewrite `becomeFan` in this new system?

```
becomeFan name title = 
  Map.alter update title where
    update Nothing  = Nothing -- that title was not in our database
    update (Just f) = Just (f { fans = Set.insert name (fans f) })
```

now we're leaning mostly on `Map.alter :: (Maybe v -> Maybe v) -> k -> Map k v -> Map k v` and `Set.insert :: a -> Set a -> Set a` to do our heavy lifting and maintain various uniqueness constraints. Note that the first argument to `Map.alter` is a function `Maybe v -> Maybe v` which allows for us to handle missing films (if the input is `Nothing`) and decide to remove a film from the database (if we return `Nothing`).

It's also worth noting that our inner function `update :: Maybe Film -> Maybe Film` could be more easily written as `fmap (\f = f { fans = Set.insert name (fans f) })` to lift the "pure" update step up into the `Maybe` as it is a `Functor`.

---

Can we do better? Sure, but it gets confusing here. The previous answer might be your best bet in most situations. But let's forge on for fun.

We could use lenses from [Control.Lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) to make our access into the `Map`, `Set`, and `Film` even easier.

To do this, we'll import the module

```
import Control.Lens
```

and rewrite the `Film` type so that the library can auto-generate lenses using a macro.

```
data Film = Film { _title :: Title, _cast :: Set Name, _year :: Year, _fans :: Set Name }
$(makeLenses ''Film)
```

all we have to do is prepend an underscore to each record field name and `Control.Lens.makeLenses` will automatically generate our lenses under the original names. Thus, after that line we have functions like `title :: Lens' Film Title` which is just what we wanted.

Then we can use `Map`'s `At` instance to create our alteration function, pretty much as before, but written as a string of lens operations

```
becomeFan name film = over (at film) (fmap . over fans . Set.insert $ name)
```

where `over (at film)` generalizes and replaces `Map.alter` and `(fmap . over fans . Set.insert $ name)` replaces our `update` inner functions we defined previously.

We can even construct a powerful setter lens which looks directly at the existence of a certain fan in the fans list of a certain `Film`.

```
isFan :: Name -> String -> Setter' Database Bool
isFan name film = at film . mapped . fans . contains name
```

These methods are fairly obnoxious at first and have very strange (but fully checkable) types, but they become very nice once you become used to working at that level of abstraction. It "reads like English" and feels like the good parts of XPath.

```
becomeFan name film = isFan name film .~ True
```

and with this construction we can even upgrade the whole process immediately into the `State` monad.

```
flip execState initialDB $ do
  isFan "Joseph" "7 1/2"        .= True
  isFan "Steve"  "Citizen Kane" .= True
  -- oh, wait, nevermind
  isFan "Joseph" "7 1/2"        .= False
```

Though, we could do the same with `Control.Monad.State.withState` using any definition of `becomeFan`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I you haven't really shown anything specific, I'll just offer some general hints..

```
add :: String -> String -> Database -> Database
add name film db = (film, cast, year, name : fans) : filteredDb
  where (_, cast, year, fans) = get the movie
        filtered_db = remove the entry about ${film} from the db
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you started, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: What specifics have I missed out that may be required? And thanks for the answer much appreciated :)

Comment: What? I'm sorry i don't follow. I've summarized what `fans` and `filtered_db` have to be. If you can get those working then you're all set

Comment: By "specifics", I think jozefg means that you didn't tell us if you've tried to write the function, what it looked like, and what problems you were having. See Floris' first comment on your question. It's easier to help someone if we know what part of the task they're having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of going about it.

```
becomeFan :: Title -> Fan -> Database -> Database
becomeFan title newFan = map f where
    f film @ (title', cast, year, fans)
        | title == title' = --TODO
        | otherwise       = --TODO
```